# xargs command results in sed: ;: No such file or directory

Tags: xargs

Trying to search and replace recursively across multiple files on a mac running OS X using the following command:

```
grep -rl string1 ./ | xargs sed -i ''  s/string1/string2/g \;
```

but it returns the following error:

```
sed: ;: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\;` at the end:

```
grep -rl string1 ./ | xargs sed -i ''  s/string1/string2/g
```

Comment: As an explanation: @Das probably copy and pasted from a `find` command, which expects a `\;` after the last arg to the `-exec` option.